# jQuery.createUploadForm is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, ajax-upload

I am using [ajaxupload](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/) for uploading and using jQuery 1.7.2. I got an error like this

```
TypeError: jQuery.createUploadForm is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

... jQuery.createUploadForm(id, s.fileElementId, (typeof(s.data)=='undefined'?false...
```

my code is

```
function ajaxFileUpload()
    {
        jQuery.ajaxFileUpload
        (
            {
                url:'<?php echo $currenturl.&fileupload=enable;?>',
                secureuri:false,
                fileElementId:'fileToUpload',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data, status)
                {
                    if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
                    {
                        if(data.error != '')
                        {
                            alert(data.error);
                        }else
                        {
                            alert(data.msg);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )

        return false;

    }
```

and the html is

```
<div class="upload-button"><input type="button" value="upload" id="upload-btn" onclick="return ajaxFileUpload();"/></div>
```

Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems you haven't included your jQuery-plugin or did it in wrong order

Comment: i checked through jsviewer it is included

Comment: is this a wordpress or other cms site with self loading plugins from an admin? If so... see my answer edit and check you don;t have multiple instances of jQuery.js loading

Answer (score 1):

The `is not a function` error can be caused by several things... most common are:

- Path to plugin file is incorrect or not included in page at all. Easy to check in browser console that it is being loaded as a page resource
- Order of scripts loading is incorrect. Plugin must load before you
  try to use it
- jQuery.js not loading before all plugins and dependent code

**EDIT:** Another really common issue, especially on wordpress sites, is loading extra versions of jQuery after some plugins have loaded. If jQuery is loaded a second time after prior plugins load, it wipes them out

Comment: thanks for your there is 2 jquery.js files are included after removing one i got like this TypeError: jQuery.handleError is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

jQuery.handleError(s, xml, status, e);

Comment: jQuery must load prior to any plugins, problem is likely just ordering the script tags

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included `jquery.js` before the plugin js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myplugin.js"></script>
```

Also, avoid using the antiquated `on*` attributes in HTML. As you're already using jQuery in your function, you can simply attach a click handler to the element to run the function like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#upload-btn").click(ajaxFileUpload);
});
```

Comment: That is a good suggestion, but looking at the error it seems that is not the source of the problem.

Comment: @Asad loading `jquery.js` after the `plugin.js` would cause this issue.

Comment: He would most likely get a different error from the plugin itself if he tried doing that.

Comment: i include first jquery.js and then include the plugin now i got error like this TypeError: jQuery.ajaxFileUpload is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

success: function (data, status)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code into `$(document).ready(function(){...});` event

Comment: `$(document).ready` has no bearing on a function not available

Comment: The idea is, maybe he needs to do some initialization code before using the click event and that code doesn't work because is not initialized in document ready event. But I admit, I don't know how the plugin works